# Infinite loop in python causes Quickly App to freeze

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to develop an Ubuntu App using Quickly. When I run an infinite loop in python the Ubuntu App freezes and stops responding. The following is the code I used:

```
 # Code for other initialization actions should be added here.

    self.startbutton = self.builder.get_object("startbutton")
def on_startbutton_clicked(self,widget):
    while 1 :
        if "100" in open("file1.txt").read():
            print "success"
            exit ()
```

When I write 100 into file.txt, the terminal prints success but the Ubuntu App will still not respond. So what should I change in my code so that my App won't freeze?

I have changed my while loop

```
 flag=1
    while flag :
        fp = open("file1.txt","r")
        if fp.read()=="100":
            print "success"
            flag=0
        fp.close()
```

Even then the App freezes

Comment: Stop using an infinite loop.

Comment: You realize that you are constantly opening a file and not closing it?

Comment: But I need to read the file continuously because when I enter 100 into that file I'll create a new guest virtual machine. So I should use infinite loop, Is there any alternative to infinite loop?

Comment: An infinite loop that breaks on a condition, so it doesn't stop there forever checking?

Comment: The loop exits when it reads 100 from that file

Comment: @sgu: But do you really want to tell the App to freeze until you enter 100 into the file? Incidentally, I imagine you meant `break` not `exit()`.

Comment: @Hurkyl I just want the App to wait untill I enter 100 and then I can carry on with other functions later,  but it freezes and doesn't respond. And also I meant break and not exit(). What about my new while loop? it also results in same problem

Comment: @sgu "I want the App to wait" ... "I want the App to respond". Those are contradictory desires. What you want the App to *continue running*, while keeping an eye on the file so that it will do something new when it contains 100. Maybe it does so by *periodically* checking the file while still running its event loop normally or by spawning a new thread dedicated to the task or somesuch.